# Reading K3 / K3-Pro Thermometer using WebUSB

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I just came across WebUSB and new to this API.
I am looking at capturing from my web application 2 fields, 1 from the USB barcode scanner and the other from a USB K3/K3-Pro Thermometer device the temperature.

With only the barcode scanner, i have no issue previously as it act as a keyboard input to the field.

How do go about using WebUSB to perform this task for multiple input devices?